# Tab bar items not connecting to VIEW

Tags: ios, tabs

This may sound like a silly question but I have created a single VIEW then added a TAB BAR at the bottom.. I want to connect the TAB ITEMS to new VIEWS but when I go to CTRL DRAG to a new VIEW CONTROLLER it will not connect??
Am I doing something wrong?
CHeers
MAt

Comment: Personally, I find it easier to use a [tab bar controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW1) (especially if you're doing it with storyboards), not a tab bar, itself.

Comment: Yes ok! I have done that now!!

Comment: However I need to goto another view from my FirstViewController via a button and although I have created a PAGE VIEW CONTROLLER and then linked it to the button I cannot do anything to it??? Any idea why?

Comment: Should be fine. Are you saying that you page view controller works outside of a tab bar controller, but not in it? I would suspect that something else is going on there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with a tabBar. You need to implement the UITabBarDelegate method, tabBar:didSelectItem:, and do the transitions in code. As Rob said though, it would be easier to use a TabBarController.

Comment: Hi.. I have created a TAbBarController and then from one of the tab views i need to goto another view via a button.. How can I do that? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi.. worked it out.. VIEW CONTROLLER all working great and created h & m files.. although when i created NEW FILES i had to remove references to NIB files to get it to come up in the CLASS drop down boxes when I was attaching them to the VIEW CONTROLLERS!!